# in Python 3, how can I slice JSON data where objects all start with same name?

Tags: json, parsing, slice

I have a JSON string that returns device info and if devices are found, the devices will be listed as device0, device1, device2, etc. In this simple code below, how can I discover all devices found in the JSON and then print the the info below for each device? I currently lookup each device statically and I want this discovery to be dynamic and print the results for each one found.

```
r1 = requests.get(url = url_api, params = PARAMS)

devicedata = r1.json()

if 'device0' in devicedata:
        print('')
        device0Name = (devicedata['device0']['device_name'])
        print(device0Name)
        print('Temp: {}'.format (devicedata['device0']['obs'][0]['ambient_temp']))
        print('Probe Temp: {}'.format (devicedata['device0']['obs'][0]['probe_temp']))
        print('Humidity: {}%'.format (devicedata['device0']['obs'][0]['humidity']))
        print('')
```

# JSON info looks like this...

```
{'device0': {'success': True, 'device_type': 'TX60', 'obs': [{'device_id': '1111', 'device_type': 'TX60', 'u_timestamp': '1580361017', 'ambient_temp': '45.7', 'probe_temp': '45.5', 'humidity': '82', 'linkquality': '100', 'lowbattery': '0', 'success': '9', 's_interval': '99', 'timestamp': '1/29/2020 11:10 PM', 'utctime': 1580361017}], 'alerts': {'miss': {'id': '520831', 'alert_type': 'miss', 's_id': '1111', 'max': '-100', 'min': '30', 'wet': '0', 'alert_id': '1', 'phone': 'yes', 'email': '', 'state': None}, 'batt': {'id': '520832', 'alert_type': 'batt', 's_id': '1111', 'max': '-100', 'min': '-100', 'wet': '0', 'alert_id': '1', 'phone': 'yes', 'email': '', 'state': None}}, 'ispws': 0, 'unit': {'temp': '&deg;F', 'temp2': '&deg;F', 'rh': '%'}, 'device_id': '1111', 'expired': '0', 'interval': '30', 'reg_date': '2020-01-17 22:06:48', 'create_date': 1579298808, 'device_name': 'Back Yard', 'assocGateway': '1', 'problem': False}, 'device1': {'success': True, 'device_type': 'TX60', 'obs': [{'device_id': '2222', 'device_type': 'TX60', 'u_timestamp': '1580360303', 'ambient_temp': '63.6', 'probe_temp': 'N/C', 'humidity': '64', 'linkquality': '100', 'lowbattery': '0', 'success': '9', 's_interval': '99', 'timestamp': '1/29/2020 10:58 PM', 'utctime': 1580360303}], 'alerts': {'miss': {'id': '520220', 'alert_type': 'miss', 's_id': '2222', 'max': '-100', 'min': '30', 'wet': '0', 'alert_id': '1', 'phone': 'yes', 'email': '', 'state': None}, 'batt': {'id': '520221', 'alert_type': 'batt', 's_id': '2222', 'max': '-100', 'min': '-100', 'wet': '0', 'alert_id': '1', 'phone': 'yes', 'email': '', 'state': None}}, 'ispws': 0, 'unit': {'temp': '&deg;F', 'temp2': '&deg;F', 'rh': '%'}, 'device_id': '3333', 'expired': '1', 'interval': '30', 'reg_date': '2016-03-19 01:45:04', 'create_date': 1500868369, 'device_name': 'Crawl Space', 'assocGateway': '1', 'problem': False}, 'device2': {'success': True, 'device_type': 'TX60', 'obs': [{'device_id': '3333', 'device_type': 'TX60', 'u_timestamp': '1580360195', 'ambient_temp': '70.2', 'probe_temp': 'N/C', 'humidity': '48', 'linkquality': '100', 'lowbattery': '0', 'success': '9', 's_interval': '99', 'timestamp': '1/29/2020 10:56 PM', 'utctime': 1580360195}], 'alerts': None, 'ispws': 0, 'unit': {'temp': '&deg;F', 'temp2': '&deg;F', 'rh': '%'}, 'device_id': '3333', 'expired': '0', 'interval': '15', 'reg_date': '2020-01-30 04:34:00', 'create_date': 1580358840, 'device_name': 'Basement', 'assocGateway': '2', 'problem': False}, 'tz': 'America/Chicago'}
```

The output for a single device looks like this..

```
Back Yard
Temp: 50.9
Probe Temp: 51.2
Humidity: 92%


Crawl Space
Temp: 65.4
Probe Temp: N/C
Humidity: 55%


Basement
Temp: 70
Probe Temp: N/C
Humidity: 48%
```

Comment: Are you able to change the format of the JSON at all. If you are, then switching to:
`{ 'devices': {'device0': {}, 'device1': {}, 'device2': {}},
   'tz': 'America/Chicago'
}
then you could take the devices object, and parse the array of them. if the deviceNames are not relevant, then just switch to an array and cycle through the array

Comment: No. The JSON data is provided after calling via requests

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but you might be interested to learn about the [f string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) supported by Python 3, because writing `.format` is no longer necessary.

Comment: Yes. Understand. I use both and this is just sample code

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
for devKey in devicedata.keys():
    if "device" in devKey:
        dev = devicedata[devKey]
        name = dev["device_name"]
        obs = dev["obs"][0]
        temp = obs["ambient_temp"]
        probeTemp = obs["probe_temp"]
        humidity = obs["humidity"]
        print(name)
        print('Temp: {}'.format(temp))
        print('Probe Temp: {}'.format(probeTemp))
        print('Humidity: {}%'.format(humidity))
        print('')
```